# getjson and utf-8 issue

Tags: jquery, encoding, utf-8, getjson

For a mobile application I get my data from a odata json rest service. The service is written correctly, if I go straight to the link of the service, I see all the characters correctly.

However, I get the data using .getJSON and then with a loop place it on my screen. Names with special characters don't show well, I see a square with a questionmark.

I have tried setting the encoding of my html to utf-8.

In my code I have also tried this:

```
var uri_encode = encodeURIComponent(name);
var testname = decodeURIComponent( escape (uri_encode));
console.log(testname);
```

The console gives: M%EF%BF%BDller

How could I solve this issue?